# Overlapping box elements

Tags: html, css

Please look at the image to understand what I am talking about. I have three box elements that look like what is displayed in the picture. What I want is for the green box to only be displayed overlapping the yellow and **not** displayed over overlapping the red. The green box needs to reside overlapping both but only visible over the yellow area. Ive tried using z-index, position and opacity in every different manner I could think of, but yet to come up with a solution.

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELksG.png)

```
<div id="one" ></div>
<div id="two" >
</div><div id="three" ></div>


#one{
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
#two{
    margin-left: 50px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
}
#three{
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your markup and css

Comment: what will happen with the green box portion that is hidden under the red? Why not just cut the green in half and only show the portion thats on the yellow? Otherwise sounds like your z-indexes will be conflicting with one another. 
If you cut the green in half and then resize it with jquery it can show over the red when needed if your use case requires that

Comment: Put your green box in the yellow box with an absolute position. Set the overflow on the yellow box to hidden.

Comment: it depends on your html structure. post that please.

Comment: @Lewis thanks man. overflow did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to have elements overlap one layer and then go underneath another layer like you are asking. I know there is some art term for this.

Anyways here is the closest solution is to just fake it and have the green box inside the yellow box:

```css
.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.green {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 3;
}

.yellow {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="yellow">
    <div class="green"></div>       
  </div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Were you thinking of "Mask"?

Comment: I was thinking of like impossible objects I guess they are called Penrose objects but doesn't truly apply here xD

Comment: Anyways I like Lewis' answer in the comments, position the green box at it's full width halfway outside of the yellow box, then put overflow: hidden on the yellow box.